# Batch command delete from list of files from multiple computers

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Currently I use a poor piece of programming where I delete multiple files on  multiple PC's.

What I would like to do is have a file with the names of the PC's (PC.txt) and a file (filedel.txt) with a list of the files to delete, run a batch file which reads both and does the work and be able to just update the text files once rather than at the moment doing it the painful way. The files are in different folders aswell.

I have been looking at this for ages, I cannot get anywhere with it. Currently I run this program from each PC and have to update every PC, whereas I should be able to just run it from 1 and update the 2 files on that.

Currently I run this individaully on each PC

```
cd /d "w:\Profile\*****\Documents\KDS Updaters\"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type Filedel.txt') do (
  del "%%~a" /q
  PAUSE
)
```

Comment: The first question is, do you know if you have permission to delete these files from another machine. It may be permissions won't let you, but, there is no reason you can't run a bat from a central place, but you will need to have this tool set up on each PC (in task scheudler)

Comment: Hi Dave, Yes I have full admin rights, I was hoping to be able to add in some way of reading a text file that called the computer name \\?????\c$ etc

Comment: Ohh, I see where you are coming from, host the filedel.txt centrally you mean? Yes, that could work, thanks for your help, I shall go have a look into that now.

Answer (score 1):

try this the computer needs to be on the same network

pulled from this link. Just in case the link goes dead i posted the answer too. https://fraaargh.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/remotly-launch-a-batch-file-on-a-windows-computer/

```
set machine=targetMachine
set file=\\eici01\user\FMA\test.bat
set user=toto
set userPwd=myPassword
set executeAs=%user%
set executeAsPwd=%userPwd%
schtasks /Create /S %machine% /U %user% /P %userPwd% /RU %executeAs% /RP %executeAsPwd% /SC ONCE /TN install /TR %file% /ST 00:00:00
schtasks /Run /S %machine% /U %user% /P %userPwd% /TN install
pause
```